# Location of MyPublisher files on Win XP?

Tags: windows-xp, file-location

Desperately trying to find MyPublisher book files (large file size) to get off a Win XP notebook I am selling. It's my wife's laptop, and she has about 12 large books on there, so I know the files add up to GBs of space taken. Still, I cannot find these files anywhere. And the actual MyPublisher application is only MBs in size, so I know the files aren't in the actual app itself. Does anyone know where these book files are stored on Win XP.

PS. I do know that you can export. I did that, but I also want to find the files so I can save them in non-exported format, and then delete them to free up many GBs of space.

Google gave no info on this, even after multiple queries.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in with the user account which was used to create the books, and make sure MyPublisher is closed.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `%appdata%\MyPublisher\MyPublisher`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Open the `books.xml` file, which contains the book list. Here's an example of the file content:

   ```xml
   <bookname.0 xsi:type="mypub:string">Book0</bookname.0>
   <bookguid.0 xsi:type="mypub:string">GF7956115_9B23_44BB_6E91_203E52005EE8</bookguid.0>
   ```

   The actual book files are stored in a subfolder named after the book ID (e.g. `GF7956115_9B23_44BB_6E91_203E52005EE8`). The book names help you understand which is which.
4. Copy all book folders and the `books.xml` file. After you copied everything you can delete the original folders to regain space.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the subfolder named after the book ID (e.g. `GF7956115_9B23_44BB_6E91_203E52005EE8`) there is another .XML file which describes the entire book layout.

**WARNING:** that XML file also has hardcoded "absolute" paths to the ORIGINAL PHOTOS you used to make the book in their ORIGINAL LOCATION. Even though the BookMaker app has all those JPG files under the book folder, you still need to save the ORIGINAL input files (as well as their path and filenames).

Comment: I've had trouble when trying to SHARE or ORDER books with the software. To fix it, I've had to go into the subfolder named after the book ID, and DELETE all the JPG files, leaving only the XML, PDF and a few other files (under 10 files in total).